# Could not run jar file in hadoop3.1.3

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop3

I tried this command in command prompt (run as administrator):

```
hadoop jar C:\Users\tejashri\Desktop\Hadoopproject\WordCount.jar  WordcountDemo.WordCount  /work /out
```

but i got this error message:
my application got stopped.

```
2020-04-04 23:53:27,918 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2020-04-04 23:53:28,881 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2020-04-04 23:53:28,951 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/tejashri/.staging/job_1586024027199_0006
2020-04-04 23:53:29,162 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-04-04 23:53:29,396 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
2020-04-04 23:53:29,570 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-04-04 23:53:29,762 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-04-04 23:53:29,802 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
2020-04-04 23:53:30,059 INFO sasl.SaslDataTransferClient: SASL encryption trust check: localHostTrusted = false, remoteHostTrusted = false
2020-04-04 23:53:30,156 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1586024027199_0006
2020-04-04 23:53:30,156 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []
2020-04-04 23:53:30,504 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
2020-04-04 23:53:30,507 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
2020-04-04 23:53:30,586 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1586024027199_0006
2020-04-04 23:53:30,638 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://LAPTOP-2UBC7TG1:8088/proxy/application_1586024027199_0006/
2020-04-04 23:53:30,640 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1586024027199_0006
2020-04-04 23:53:35,676 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1586024027199_0006 running in uber mode : false
2020-04-04 23:53:35,679 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2020-04-04 23:53:35,698 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1586024027199_0006 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1586024027199_0006 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1586024027199_0006_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2020-04-04 23:53:34.955]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.
"Setting up env variables"
"Setting up job resources"
"Copying debugging information"

C:\hadoop\hdfstmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\tejashri\appcache\application_1586024027199_0006\container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001>rem Creating copy of launch script

C:\hadoop\hdfstmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\tejashri\appcache\application_1586024027199_0006\container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001>copy "launch_container.cmd" "C:/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1586024027199_0006/container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001/launch_container.cmd"
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\hadoop\hdfstmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\tejashri\appcache\application_1586024027199_0006\container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001>rem Determining directory contents

C:\hadoop\hdfstmp\nm-local-dir\usercache\tejashri\appcache\application_1586024027199_0006\container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001>dir  1>>"C:/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1586024027199_0006/container_1586024027199_0006_02_000001/directory.info"
"Launching container"


[2020-04-04 23:53:34.959]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


[2020-04-04 23:53:34.960]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://LAPTOP-2UBC7TG1:8088/cluster/app/application_1586024027199_0006 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
2020-04-04 23:53:35,743 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: `'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, Is `JAVA_HOME` set? Can you run `javac -version` in command prompt and post what it returns?

Comment: java version

C:\Windows\System32>javac -version

javac 1.8.0_171


C:\Windows\System32>java -version

java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)


yes, i have set java_home

Comment: What is the output of `hadoop version`

Comment: Hadoop 3.1.3
Source code repository https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r ba631c436b806728f8ec2f54ab1e289526c90579
Compiled by ztang on 2019-09-12T02:47Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum ec785077c385118ac91aadde5ec9799
This command was run using /C:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.3.jar

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` configured in `hadoop-env.cmd` file?

Comment: yes, I have done that

@rem The java implementation to use.  Required.
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"

this is the path i have set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

The `JAVA_HOME` variable is not properly set in `hadoop-env.cmd`.

Also, move the JDK installation to a folder without whitespaces (say, `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171`)

Update the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables

Add this line in `hadoop-env.cmd`,

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
```

Restart the hadoop daemons and run the Job.